# Check the domain availability via Python and Godaddy API

Tags: python, json, api, google-api-python-client

I have a list of domain names in txt file ('links.txt') and I want to check it's availability and write it in different txt file ('available_domains.txt') if it is available. I wrote the code like:

```
import requests
import time
import json

api_key = "3mM44UaguNL6GH_Kc3bKzig25G1mZtnA87nwS"
secret_key = "37ZnMbQkQrYJ5pF57ZhrEi"

headers = {"Authorization" : "sso-key {}:{}".format(api_key, secret_key)}

url = "https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/available"
appraisal = "https://api.godaddy.com/v1/appraisal/{}"

do_appraise = True

with open("links.txt") as f:
    for domains in f:
        availability_res = requests.post(url, json=domains, headers=headers)
        for domain in json.loads(availability_res.text)['domains']:
            if domain['available']:
                with open("available_domains.txt", 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
                    f.write(domain)
            else:
                print("Not Available")
```

But I'm getting error like:

```
for domain in json.loads(availability_res.text)["domains"]:
KeyError: 'domains'
```

I'm new in it. And I don't think my code is that correct. If you have any idea can you help me with it??

Answer (score 1):

I have found your issue.

You need to define the "domain" using the "params" flag of the get requests function.

Here is a little snippet that worked for me (you will need to incorporate it into your for loop)

```
api_key = "YOURKEYHERE"
secret_key = "YOURKEYHERE"

headers = {"Authorization": "sso-key {}:{}".format(api_key, secret_key)}
url = "https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/available"
test = get(url, params={'domain':'google.co.uk'}, headers=headers).text
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been tasked to do the same thing in python.
Thanks to this blog[Godaddy domain name API in Python](https://www.8bitavenue.com/godaddy-domain-name-api-in-python/) I was able to complete this task.
Try it out

Answer (score -2):

This error occur because of the limit of requests you can send per minute you have to add time.sleep(48) after every 20 request in this way yo will not get this error

Comment: Using `sleep` is never a good idea. Sure, it might achieve what you want, but the issues it might also raise are not worth it.